# Will aria attributes be visible to screen readers and be valid if I set them through javascript?

Tags: javascript, wai-aria

I am developing an accordion and I wonder if I could insert aria attributes with javascript. I used bootstrap and it has all aria markup initially. Is there any reason for it? Does screen readers see aria attributes which are inserted dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

It's common to insert and change aria attributes with JavaScript after page load. In some cases it's necessary to add and remove attributes during user interaction. It should work correctly in the latest versions of popular screen readers as NVDA, VoiceOver and JAWS.

However this isn't absolutely fool-proof, cause some very old screen readers build the accessibility tree once the page loaded without any updates later.